# Squid proxy on ubuntu 12.04 times out for everything

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

On my freshly imaged virtual private server, I just finished installing squid version 3.1.19. As expected, the default configuration didn't work. So, I saved the original config file and created a ew one with two lines, namely:

```
http_access allow all                                                                                                     
http_port 3128
```

I know it defeats the purpose of having a proxy for almost all intents and purposes but this is just to test if I can get a successful connection to any place, as mundane as yahoo.com. Yet, I can not. Regardless whichever site I try to hit, I get a screen saying, ERROR The reuested URL could not be retrieved. And in the access log I see the following immediately after I type the url and hit enter:

```
1391456766.727     68 w.x.y.z TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://yahoo.com/ - DIRECT/yahoo.com -           
1391456825.489  60281 w.x.y.z TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4002:c02::63 -         
1391456825.489  60095 w.x.y.z TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4002:c02::63 -         
1391456856.560  61309 w.x.y.z TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4002:c02::63 -         
1391456949.142 182387 w.x.y.z TCP_MISS/504 4044 GET http://10.216.124.6:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi? - DIRECT/10.216.124.6 text/html                                                                                                        
1391457129.393 179732 w.x.y.z TCP_MISS/504 3862 GET http://10.216.124.6:15871/favicon.ico - DIRECT/10.216.124.6 text/html
```

The yahoo URL is where I am trying to go to, the google URLS, I beleieve, are my chrome browser wants to contact the mother ship and the 10.216 URLS are something that I have no idea what they are about.

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get this thing working